# Does this Prolog program have a simple proof of non-halting?

Tags: prolog

```
:-  p(f(X),f(f(Y)),f(f(b))).

p(f(a),f(X),f(f(X))).
p(f(a),f(a),f(f(X))).
p(X,f(f(Y)),X) :- p(Y,f(f(Y)),f(f(X))).
p(f(X),Y,Z) :- p(X,f(Y),f(f(Z))).
```

I believe I have a proof that uses induction and requires several subcases, some of which are:

```
p(f(X),f(f(X)),f(f(b))) grows (i.e. does not halt) is a corollary from:

p( X, f^n(X), f^(n+1)(b) ) grows (i.e. does not halt)

p(f^k(b),f^l(b),f^m(b)) fails if 0 <= k < m.

p(f^k(b),f^l(b),f^k(b)) fails if l-k mod 3 = 0

where f^n(X) means n iterations: f(f(...f(X)...)).
```

I will try to complete the proof, but am wondering if there is a much simpler proof of non-halting. By 'halting' I assume the standard Prolog procedural semantics: sequential ordering of clauses and (although it is irrelevant in this example) left-to-right execution of subgoals.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog we talk usually about universal and existential termination. Universal termination being the more relevant. A goal `G_0` terminates universally, iff `G_0, false` fails finitely.  So let's consider the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) of your program:

```
:-  p(f(X),f(f(Y)),f(f(b))), false.

p(f(a),f(X),f(f(X))) :- false.
p(f(a),f(a),f(f(X))) :- false.
p(X,f(f(Y)),X) :- false, p(Y,f(f(Y)),f(f(X))).
p(f(X),Y,Z) :- p(X,f(Y),f(f(Z))), false.
```

If this failure slice does not terminate, then also the entire program does not terminate. This is one of the desirable properties of pure Prolog programs.

Clearly, neither `Y` nor `Z` have any effect on termination. Both (in this failure slice) are termination neutral. So what remains is the first argument which causes the program to terminate, if it is bound (finite and ground).  With a single inference, this first `f(X)` is stripped away and an (unaliased) variable remains. Thus, this program (with the given query) does not terminate universally. □

Now for existential termination. That is, while the program does not terminate universally it may still find a solution. Think of a query like

```
?- length(L,N).
   L = [], N = 0
;  L = [_A], N = 1
;  L = [_A,_B], N = 2
;  L = [_A,_B,_C], N = 3
;  ... .
?- length(L,N), false.
   loops.
```

which does not terminate universally, but still produces useful answers and thus terminates existentially.

Often there is a shortcut for existential termination: If there is no solution and the program does not terminate universally, then it also does not terminate existentially. That would be a quick shot! Alas, that is not the case here. One such solution is

```
?- p(f(f(a)),f(f(b)),f(f(b))).
   true
;  false.
```

and there are many more. So it is still open whether or not this program will find a solution.

Here is now one thing that strikes me as odd: The third clause serves no purpose (except for non-termination). I have observed this by adding an extra parameter to get iterative deepening:

```
% p([n],_,_,_).
p([a],f(a),f(X),f(f(X))).
p([b],f(a),f(a),f(f(X))).
p([c|L],X,f(f(Y)),X) :- p(L,Y,f(f(Y)),f(f(X))).
p([d|L],f(X),Y,Z) :- p(L,X,f(Y),f(f(Z))).

?- length(L,N), p(L, A1,A2,f(f(b))).
   L = "a", N = 1, A1 = f(a), A2 = f(b)
;  L = "b", N = 1, A1 = f(a), A2 = f(a)
;  L = "da", N = 2, A1 = f(f(a)), A2 = f(f(b))
;  L = "db", N = 2, A1 = f(f(a)), A2 = a
;  L = "dda", N = 3, A1 = f(f(f(a))), A2 = f(f(f(b)))
;  L = "ddda", N = 4, A1 = f(f(f(f(a)))), A2 = f(f(f(f(b))))
;  L = "dddda", N = 5, A1 = f(f(f(f(f(a))))), A2 = f(f(f(f(f(b)))))
;  L = "ddddda", N = 6, A1 = f(f(f(f(f(f(a)))))), A2 = f(f(f(f(f(f(b))))))
;  L = "dddddda", N = 7, A1 = f(f(f(f(f(f(f(a))))))), A2 = f(f(f(f(f(f(f(b)))))))
;  ... .
```

So when using the third rule initially once, there are no solutions to be found, and the program will not terminate. Thus proving that this part will find no solutions is tantamount to proving that the goal `p(X,f(f(X)),f(f(f(f(b)))))` has no solution.

I have not done this part, but it seems that the argument can be narrowed down to the observation that the first argument will always be of the form `f*a`, but the second of the form `f*b` and thus there cannot be a solution.